# Start date and end date from SQL procedure with JDBC

Tags: java, sql, date, jdbc

I have a procedure in SQL that sets some date limits. Later I will need this date for other queries. I have tried to call the procedure with JDBC like this :

```
public void setInterval(){
        Query query = emJAGS.createNativeQuery("DECLARE "
                + "dStartDate date :=  ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, - 60);"
                + "dEndDate date := ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, - 1);"
                + "begin "
                + "table.Setlimits( dStartDate, dEndDate);"
                + "end;");
        List<Object[]> v = query.getResultList();
        System.out.println("The limits are " +v);
    }
```

but I got an error like inavlid SQL statement although the query runs on its own. 
I should set them as out parameters , but I am not sure how to do this. Does anybody have any suggestions ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: no, they are not. You mean I should set the date from java ?